# how to remove node from soap[ response

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, soap

getting this

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns1="https://magentolocal.com/soap/default?services=CustomapiV1"> 
   <env:Body>
      <ns1:CustomapiV1ProductInventoryUpdateResponse>
         <result>1</result>
      </ns1:CustomapiV1ProductInventoryUpdateResponse>
   <env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

need this

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns1="https://**{{host}}**/soap/default?services=CustomapiV1">
```

**Second option**

If I can remove the Envelope row
or Need this

```
<env:Body>
  <ns1:CustomapiV1ProductInventoryUpdateResponse>
     <result>1</result>
  </ns1:CustomapiV1ProductInventoryUpdateResponse>
<env:Body>
```

Comment: Do you want to change the domain in the envelope? Because removing it will cause some damage in the receiving end

Comment: @Rus0 Yes I want to change the domain in the envelope, Could you help me out?